# Qt: qthread destroyed while thread is still running during closing

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a class:

```
class centralDataPool : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    centralDataPool(QObject * parent = 0);
    ~centralDataPool();
    commMonitor commOverWatch;

private:
    QThread monitorThread;
    int totalNum;

signals:
    void createMonitor(int);
};
```

In its constructor I did:

```
centralDataPool::centralDataPool(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent),totalNum(0)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(createMonitor(int)), &commOverWatch, SLOT(createMonitor(int)));
    commOverWatch.moveToThread(&monitorThread);
    monitorThread.start();
}
```

when I called the destructor of this class I get the error message:

```
qthread destroyed while thread is still running
```

But when I tried to terminate the monitorThread in the destructor of class centralDataPool,

```
centralDataPool::~centralDataPool()
{
    monitorThread.terminate();
}
```

I get memory leakage.

What is the correct way to terminate a thread during the destruction of its owner object ?

Comment: Where is your destructor code?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira See the edits.

Comment: You should not finish a thread like this. Look at the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, Hi, I have tried to add wait() or switch to quit(), but none of them works...Could you give more hints?

Comment: Have you called `monitorThread.setTerminationEnabled(true);` before calling `terminate();`?

Comment: But the compiler said that this method is not accessible?

Comment: Oh! I've missed that. It is a static protected method, so it is not possible to call it without inheriting from `QThread`. In this case, you must somehow signal the method being executed at the thread that it must end. Anyway, this is the most correct way to do this without leaking.

Comment: Try together: monitorThread.quit(); monitorThread.wait(); in destructor

Comment: You should declare QThread as pointer because it is garbage collected as soon as it goes out of the scope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should note that if you have a loop running in a function of your thread, you should explicitly end it in order to properly terminate the thread.

You can have a member variable in your class named `finishThread` which should be set  to `true` when the application is going to close. Just provide a slot in which you set the value for `finishThread`. When you want to terminate the thread emit a signal that is connected to that slot with a `true` value. `finishThread` should be provided in the loop condition to end it when it is set to `true`. After that wait for the thread to finish properly for some seconds and force it to terminate if it did not finish.

So you can have in your destructor :

```
emit setThreadFinished(true); //Tell the thread to finish
monitorThread->quit();
if(!monitorThread->wait(3000)) //Wait until it actually has terminated (max. 3 sec)
{
    monitorThread->terminate(); //Thread didn't exit in time, probably deadlocked, terminate it!
    monitorThread->wait(); //We have to wait again here!
}
```

Comment: I can call destructor via way? delete object; object.deleteLAter(); object->~Class();